# Использование переменной из цикла для наименования столбцов в R

Tags: циклы, r, именование

Имеется датафрейм со столбцом, предположим, Watch.time.Minutes. Есть необходимость в этот же самый датафрейм добавить ещё несколько столбцов, которые будут представлять собой степени исходного, а называться, соответственно, Watch.time.Minutesi, где i ∈ [2;11]. Вопрос состоит в том, как реализовать вот эту процедуру наименования в цикле, чтобы значение i из цикла автоматически трансформировалось и включалось в название столбца?

Answer (score 2):

Эта процедура в цикле реализуется буквально так, как она описана

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10)
for (i in 2:11) {
  new_var <- paste0("var_", i)
  dt[, (new_var) := a^i]
}
```

Без `data.table` не так удобно:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
df <- lapply(1:11, function(i) df$a^i)
df <- as.data.frame(df, col.names = c("a", paste0("var_", 2:11)))
```

Comment: я размышлял над этим вопросом, но так и не придумал, как обойтись без `names()`, т.е. с помощью `*apply`/`do.call`/ещё-чего-нибудь сразу присваивать столбцам имена. теоретически-то это вроде возможно.

Comment: вот так: `cbind(d, lapply(2:11, function(x){ r <- data.frame(d$a^x); names(r) <- paste0("var_", x); r}))` поэлегантнее, наверно, будет. чем у вас, а если бы ещё и от `names()` избавиться…

Comment: Вариант без `names()` уже есть, тот который с `data.table`. Он же самый эффективный из-за модификации по ссылке, в то время как остальные варианты создают ненужные копии.

Comment: Но если очень хочется сделать базовыми функциями, можно использовать `setNames()`. Или даже сразу задать имена `df <- as.data.frame(df, col.names = c("a", paste0("var_", 2:11)))` (поменял в ответе)

Comment: ещё поэкспериментировал, и, ура, всё-таки нашёл, почему `col.names` у меня не работал: если аргументом `as.data.frame()` является переменная с классом data.frame, то `col.names` молча игнорируется. надо было сбросить (или преобразовать) класс (изложил в своём ответе).

Answer (score 0):

вообще-то циклы в `r` имеет смысл применять разве что в тех случаях, когда с циклом получается быстрее и/или проще.

вот такой примерно функцией можно динамически добавить столбцы с указанными степенями указанной переменной:

```r
f <- function(d, c, e) {
  cbind(
    d,
    lapply(
      e,
      function(x) {
        as.data.frame(
          unclass(
            d[c]^x
          ),
          col.names = c(
            paste0(
              c,
              x
            )
          )
        )
      }
    )
  )
}
```

здесь:

- параметр `d` — исходная таблица
- параметр `c` — имя переменной, значения которой будут возведены в степени
- параметр `e` — вектор со степенями
- `cbind()` — объединить столбцы (аргументами передаются исходная таблица и результат выполнения `lapply()`)
- `lapply(e , function()...)` — применить к вектору `e` указанную функцию
- `as.data.frame(..., col.names=...)` — преобразовать аргумент в data.frame, дав столбцу указанное имя
- `unclass(d[c]^x)` — возвести в степень `x` содержимое переменной `d[c]` (имеющей класс data.frame), а затем убрать класс (без этого `as.data.frame()` игнорирует содержимое аргумента `col.names`)
- `paste0(c, x)` — конкатенация переменных `c` (ниже в примере содержит строку `"a"`) и `x` (в которую будут последовательно подставляться функцией `lapply()` требуемые степени)

в одну строку, без пробелов:

```r
f<-function(d,c,e){cbind(d,lapply(e,function(x){as.data.frame(unclass(d[c]^x),col.names=c(paste0(c,x)))}))}
```

а это пример применения:

```r
d <- data.frame(x=5:9, a = 1:5)
d
#>   x a
#> 1 5 1
#> 2 6 2
#> 3 7 3
#> 4 8 4
#> 5 9 5
f(d, "a", 2:4)
#>   x a a2  a3  a4
#> 1 5 1  1   1   1
#> 2 6 2  4   8  16
#> 3 7 3  9  27  81
#> 4 8 4 16  64 256
#> 5 9 5 25 125 625
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>